# How to have asserts removed in release build?

Tags: javascript, assert, babeljs, watchify

I use babelify + watchify + envify + uglify and set node_env 
`watchify ... -g [envify --NODE_ENV development]`

So I thought of having assert like this:

```
import assert from 'assert';

function debug_assert(actual, expected, message = 'AssertionError'){
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){
        assert.equal(actual, expected, message);
    }
}
```

uglify is smart enough to cut out the body of debug_assert but not actual calls to debug_assert in the code.

Without too much extra code is it possible to have assert calls properly removed from the release build?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jsfmt](https://github.com/rdio/jsfmt) and its code rewriting feature:

```
jsfmt --rewrite "assert.equal(a, b, c) -> ''" file.js
```

Haven't tested, but it might do its job. It replaces all occurrences of `assert.equal` with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'd use a combination of tools. As you have said, `envify` will convert

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){
```

to

```
if('production' !== 'production'){
```

meaning the body of the `if` will never execute.

The easiest thing you can do after that is use [`uglifyify`](https://github.com/hughsk/uglifyify) since it will perform dead code elimination and will remove the `if`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about it - I am already doing this. uglify-js removes the body of the debug_assert function however calls to debug_assert everywhere in the code base remain

Comment: Oh okay. Are you actually seeing any performance benefit to this? JS engines like V8 will just see that the function is empty and optimize it away. Are you trying to do this for performance or for build size?

Comment: Just looking for a clean solution :)

Comment: My point is that's totally subjective, haha. To me, having the asserts in there but doing nothing isn't that big a deal.